# Auto set rectangle length on canvas as per string length

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an array of strings and I have drawn those strings on screen using android graphics library (Canvas, Paint). Firstly, a transparent rectangle is drawn then on this rectangle I paint the strings, giving the impression of text with border line and filled.

**The problem is some strings are long and some are short, how can I modify the rectangle so that it is as long and as wide as the string is? (Like WRAP_CONTENT in textView)**

Currently I am using this method

```
canvas.drawRect(_x-10, _y-10, _x+620, _y+30, rectanglePaint);
canvas.drawText(placeName, _x, _y, textPaint); //text
```

If there is a better way then please do let me know.

*Note: It will be used in an AR app so the text will be moving from left to right and vice versa as the mobile is moving. _x, _y for place name works perfectly in 2nd line, I want text should remain highlighted, no matter how the mobile is moving.*

Answer (score 0):

Paint has a [measure text](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String) method that will give the width of the text if it were to be drawn with that paint. Its [get font metrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getFontMetrics(android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics)) will probably give you some data that you can calculate the height from. The sizing, positioning, wrapping and rendering of text is a very complicated problem and I would advise using a child TextView (with a background) in your ViewGroup rather than trying to roll your own if you're doing anything complicated.

Comment: is there a way I can get the length a text is covering on screen? for e.g. To make it simple for example purpose lets say, if I enclose the word "hello" in rectangle, how can i get the length of that rectangle bcx once i get that, it is all done.

Comment: `textPaint.measureText("hello")` should give you the length (in pixels)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, this worked for me :)

float len = textPaint.measureText(placeName);
canvas.drawRect(_x-10, _y-10, _x+len+15, _y+30, rectanglePaint);
canvas.drawText(placeName, _x, _y, textPaint); //text